# How to handle multiple inheritance when an exception is thrown using g++ (4.7.1 onward) with optimization O1 or more?

Tags: c++, gcc, exception, g++, gcc4.8

I tried the following code using several GCCs and got problems when I run the code which is compiled using O1 with gcc4.7.1 and onward.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

struct Interface_1
{
    virtual void setA() = 0;
};

struct Interface_2
{
    virtual void setB() = 0;
};

struct Master: Interface_1, Interface_2
{
    void setA()
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("I was thrown");
    }
    void setB()
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("I was thrown");
    }
};

int main()
{
    Master m;
    Interface_2& i2 = m;
    try
    {
        i2.setB();
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught exception e=" << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Did not catch exception" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Done running" << std::endl;
}
```

In the code above I am a reference from interface Interface_2 to refer to an object from Master class, and this will result into a crash

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  I was thrown
Abort (core dumped)
```

But it works if I use a reference from Interface_1:

```
int main()
{
    Master m;
    Interface_1& i1 = m;
    try
    {
        i1.setA();
    }
    catch (const Exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught exception e=" << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Did not catchexception" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Done running" << std::endl;
}
```

I just get what is expected:

```
Caught exception e=I was thrown
Done running
```

It seems that the first interface that I inherit from can just be used to refer to a object from Master class. I also made the inheritance from the first interface as follows:

```
class Master: public virtual Interface_1, public Interface_2
```

Then references from Interface_2 just turned out to be fine. Instead, I got problem with references from Interface_1.

I have tried this with g++ up to 4.9, and I don't know if it is working in 5.x versions.
Unfortunately I cannot just go and change the compiler's version. I should stick with 4.8 due to limitation and restriction. Therefore I wonder if you guys know any alternate/smart way to tackle this problem.

Comment: Does making the destructors virtual help?

Comment: @Galik - is there a reason to think that that would matter, or is that just superstitious programming?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @Galik: for what it's worth. No, it doesn't help.

Comment: Just FYI, this works fine when using AppleClang 7.0.2.7000181.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your code to reduce it? There's a lot of unnecessary things in here (e.g. `size()`, the extra `Exception` class) that are unnecessary to reproduce the behavior you're describing

Comment: Seems to work with [gcc6](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/zH6bObpAP0in3Ycd) and clang seems also to be fine. Maybe a bug in gcc.

Comment: @PeteBecker superstitious programming :)

Comment: @MaySam Works fine in GCC 5.3.1

Comment: @Barry: Thanks. It became straightforward. I have been trying so many different stuff, and I just lost track of it. This problem happens in an enormous code base and it was clear to me.

Comment: Thanks Galik and mkaes for the info. But changing compiler is not an option for me.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Know anything about this?